# How much disk space does 1 mini DV tape digitised in HDV take?

Tags: storage, digitisation

I'm looking out to buy some storage for a session of logging a lot of tapes, and I want to guage how much space I will need. How much disk space does 1 mini DV tape digitised in HDV take?

Comment: Why would you bother to up-res DV to HDV? It will just waste a lot of space without any quality gain.

Comment: I used this camara http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/product/broadcast-products-camcorders-hdv-dvcam/hvr-a1e/overview/ and recorded in HD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mini DV is already digital format. The bitrate is 25Mbps.
So, 1 hour occupies approximately 11 Gigabytes

Comment: Note that 25Mbps is only the video stream.  The audio stream is an additional 192kbps per channel.  Granted, that doesn't make a huge difference in the overall file size, but it does mean things end up a bit closer to 12 gigabytes per hour.

Answer (score 3):

It is approximately 11GB per hour, though I do tend to round up a bit when I make my calculations.

Digital Rebellion has a handy [Video Space Calculator](http://www.digitalrebellion.com/webapps/video_calc.html) on their website (also available as an iOS app). You can select the format, frame rate, and video length.